# How to display one particular data from Realtime Database?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

In a firebase animated list, how do you put in a conditional statement, or anything else, so that only one set of data in Realtime Database will be displayed? I currently can display all of them in a ListTile but I only want to display a destination whose name is 'Spain' and its description instead of all the database that contains Spain, Italy, USA etc.

```
class _TestDestinationsState extends State<TestDestinations> {
  final destdatabaseref = FirebaseDatabase.instance
      .reference()
      .child('Database')
      .child('Destinations');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF4D71AC),
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Eh',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                color: Colors.white)),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
          child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
            Animation<double> animation, int index) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(height: 15),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(snapshot.value['name'],
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                      subtitle: Text(snapshot.value['description'])),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
        query: destdatabaseref,
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we need to only *display* specific data from `FirebaseDatabase` we can use the following logic:

```
Visibility(
 visible: snapshot.value['name'] == 'Spain',
 child: ...
),
```

The complete snippet can be found below:

```
class _TestDestinationsState extends State<TestDestinations> {
  final destdatabaseref = FirebaseDatabase.instance
      .reference()
      .child('Database')
      .child('Destinations');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF4D71AC),
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Eh',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                color: Colors.white)),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
          child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
            Animation<double> animation, int index) {
          return Visibility(
           visible: snapshot.value['name'] == 'Spain',
           child: SingleChildScrollView(
             child: Column(
               children: [
                 SizedBox(height: 15),
                 Padding(
                   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                   child: ListTile(
                       title: Text(snapshot.value['name'],
                           style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                       subtitle: Text(snapshot.value['description'])),
                 ),
               ],
             ),
           ),
          );
        },
        query: destdatabaseref,
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

---

**However** a much better solution, would be to *retrieve* only specific data based on the filter, which can be done by filtering our query to `FirebaseDatabase` as follows:

```
final destdatabaseref = FirebaseDatabase.instance
    .reference()
    .child('Database')
    .child('Destinations')
    .orderByChild('name')
    .equalTo('Spain');
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much. Doing it through visibility widget worked but as for retrieving the data by filtering the query, it gives me thee error of "Too many positional arguments: 1 expected, but 2 found".